# Why white background color blink before correct background color appear when I use box-shadow

Tags: html, css, background-color

[image]

As the title says, you can see that before the blue background color of the button, there is a white background that appears first.
It's like a fading transition from white to blue.

How to remove white?

If I remove the box-shadow the white background won't appear?

```html
<head>
    <style>
    .tabTitle:hover {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #8080808f;
}
.btnlist .nav-item .nav-link {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #828282;
}
.btnlist .nav-item .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #2F58E2;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #2f58e250, 0px 8px 24px #2f58e250, 0px 16px 56px #2f58e250!important;
    color: #ffffff;
}
 
    </style>
</head>
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 btnlist" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item tabTitle" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-thongbao-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-thongbao" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-thongbao" aria-selected="false">button #1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item tabTitle" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link" id="pills-tienich-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-tienich" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-tienich" aria-selected="true">button #2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its seems like the button has some styles for focus state. It fires before the styles from .active class get applied.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not white but the button goes transparent for a split second. Layer the transition on top of another background. The white blink happens when the transition initializes CSS update and reloads it. It is just the transition taking place while rewriting the CSS to the new value.

Pseudo Code:

```css
.baseBackground {
     background: linear-gradient(#2F58E2, #3969ff);
}

.contact {
    background: linear-gradient(#2F58E2, #3969ff);
}

/* On change for .contact  */
.contact {
background-color: #2F58E2;
}

<div class="baseBackground">
    <div class="contact"> Changes here </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Edited my response with a Pseudo Code. Try implementing that in your code. Let me know if you face problems.